# Change CheckBoxList item style

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have application in ASP.NET with CheckBoxList:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="myCheckBoxList">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1 16" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1 17" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2 20" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I want to change style for selected elements after button click. To do that I have JavaScript fuction:

```
function changeColor() {
    var checkBoxList = document.getElementById("myCheckBoxList");
    var options = checkBoxList.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        console.log(options[i].checked);
        if (options[i].checked) {
            options[i].parentElement.className = 'Red';
        }
    }
}
```

When I click button, selected items change their colors for a very short moment (about 0,5 second) and then they back to default black color. Why my checkboxlist items style reset? I do not want this behaviour. How can I change my code to change color permamently (not just for 0,5 second)?

Comment: You changed the class name permanently, check you might have a postback or your checkboxlist items might have created again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is complete solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor() {
        var checkBoxList = $('[id$="myCheckBoxList"]');
        var options = checkBoxList[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            console.log(options[i].checked);
            if (options[i].checked) {
                options[i].parentElement.className = 'Red';
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>

<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="myCheckBoxList">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1 16" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1 17" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="2 20" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:Button OnClientClick="return changeColor();" Text="Test" runat="server" />
```

I've localized myCheckBoxList using jQuery, because it can have different Id in the browser if you are using master page. Secondly I return false from the function to prevent postback on button click in order to maintain class value.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. I probably do unintentionally postback. Of course there should be options[i].parentElement.style.color = 'Red' - my mistake